# HD capture on iPad without HDCP

Tags: ipad, video, capture, copy-protection, hdcp

I am trying to allow HD capture from my iPad app via Apple's HDMI adapter. When trying to do this with various recording devices, I get messages that say the operation is not permitted due to copyright protection. Is it possible to disable HDCP protection for my own app programmatically in some way? The techniques for otherwise capturing HD from the iPad are convoluted to impossible, stringing together various sorts of adapters that may or may not work, and may or may not give full HD resolution results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a device that works perfectly. It is the [BlackMagic H.264 Pro Recorder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005ABJ0H8). It records in H.264, up to 20KB which is nice enough for broadcast. What a relief - we tried and returned 4 or 5 other devices before finding this one. And yes, it captures the HDCP protected signal.

Comment: It can capture an HDCP protected signal?